# How to get Qt application window size from a QML file which is not the QML where the root window is declared?

Tags: qt, qml, qt5, qt5.15

While I am in a random QML file which is not the parent `main.qml`, is it possible to get the Qt application window size?

I know that I can declare the app window root in a global property like below and get the size anywhere.

```
ApplicationWindow {
    id: main_window_root
    visible: true
    width: 1000
    height: 800

    property alias main_window_root: main_window_root
}
```

But my primary question is, does Qt itself have a global property declared which can fetch the application window size?

I ask this because I see that I can get the application state, platform it is running on etc by doing a `Qt.` in any QML file. It looks like some properties are globally declared by Qt. Following is official documentation for this:
https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtqml-qt.html

Hence the question, is the application window size also accessible through some global property in QML?

I am using `Qt 5.15.8` commercial version.

Comment: Did you try `Window.width` and `Window.height`?

Comment: @JarMan Thats exactly what I was looking for!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ApplicationWindow is a Window, which provides attached properties to read the width and height. So you can use `Window.width` and `Window.height` from anywhere to get the current window's dimensions. See docs [here](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-window-window.html#height-attached-prop).